# How to send product details(image & text) as url by a click on Android Share icon

Tags: android-sharing

Do android apps require a website? I'm working on an real time android market app and wanted users to share product details and its image using android share icon but I don't know how to share that information as url coz my app is not a web app its just an android app.

Image is as shown
[image]

I wanted to share the image and data(e.gtable and 50000) using my sharing options
For possible solutions that I have come across is getting url for  the product and sharing it but I also realised that most apps that use this option have a website where they can get a shareble url from,as shown[image]

but my issue with this solution is my app doesn't have a web app/website, because it is purely android app, will I be required to have a web app/website in order to get a sharerable url? or is there an option of sharing this data?

This is what I have for my sharing button, sending out hardcoded text via code:

```
else if (id == R.id.action_share) {
 Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    String shareBodyText = "Check it out this product";
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject   here");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,  shareBodyText);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Shearing Option"));
    return true;
}
```

Comment: "share" could mean anything.. email? facebook? telegram? depends how you want to share it. if you don't have a server you can't really share a url except a datauri. clrify.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. Yes, by "share" I meant sharing on social media..whatsapp, message e.t.c

Comment: that question is entirely too broad and you didn't even post any code. there are libraries that you can look into, or you can get started with the facebook api. for simple stuff, there is a facebook library called "simple facebook" on github which is really handy and cuts the learning curve in half.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce.I don't think my question is broad, maybe you didn't understand me quite well. I have already implemented the image and texts in an activity and the sharing menu item.  **I have edited my question to include some code and illustrated pictorial***